# C++ classes: read value behave as different types

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I want to create a class similar to this:

```
class MyTime {
public:
    int seconds;
    int useconds;

    /*** functions ***/
}
```

but which has the following behavior:

```
MyTime now;
double current_time = now; // returns double representing seconds
```

Is there a way to do this without have to define an `asDoubleSeconds()` function? Can I change the behavior by overloading the assignment operator somehow?

If not, is there a way to do something like this:

```
double current_time = double(now);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, implement a [user-defined conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator):

```
class MyTime {
    // ...

    operator double() const;
};

MyTime::operator double() const {
    // compute and return a double
}
```